# Merging two rules to one rule with wildcards/dictionary

Tags: snakemake

I am mapping and counting sequences that are mixed from two species.
I have two rules in my pipeline because each specie has it's own GTF file.
I would like to be able to merge this into one rule, and then have the specie wildcard dictate which GTF file to use (using a dictionary for example).
These are the rules:

```
rule count_reads_human:
    input:
        ibam = "sorted_reads/human/{spc}_sorted.bam",
        gtf = "/nadata/users/username/annotations/hg38/gencode.v38.annotation.gtf"
    output:
        bam = "counted_reads/human/{spc}_countBAM.bam",
        htout = "counted_reads/human/{spc}_htseq_count.out"
    log:
        "logs/count_reads/human/{spc}.log"
    shell:
        "htseq-count -o {output.bam} -p bam {input.ibam} {input.gtf} > {output.htout} 2> {log}"

rule count_reads_mouse:
    input:
        ibam = "sorted_reads/mouse/{spc}_sorted.bam",
        gtf = "/nadata/users/username/annotations/mm10/gencode.vM20.annotation.gtf"
    output:
        bam = "counted_reads/mouse/{spc}_countBAM.bam",
        htout = "counted_reads/mouse/{spc}_htseq_count.out"
    log:
        "logs/count_reads/mouse/{spc}.log"
    shell:
        "htseq-count -o {output.bam} -p bam {input.ibam} {input.gtf} > {output.htout} 2> {log}"
```

What I would like to do is something of the sort:

```
gtfDict = {"human": "path/to/human/gtf/file.gtf", "mouse": "/path/to/mouse/gtf/file.gtf"}

rule count_reads:
    input:
        ibam = "sorted_reads/{specie}/{spc}_sorted.bam",
        gtf = gtfDict[{specie}]
    output:
        bam = "counted_reads/{specie}/{spc}_countBAM.bam",
        htout = "counted_reads/{specie}/{spc}_htseq_count.out"
    log:
        "logs/count_reads/{specie}/{spc}.log"
    shell:
        "htseq-count -o {output.bam} -p bam {input.ibam} {input.gtf} > {output.htout} 2> {log}"
```

My merged rule however does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to use lambda:

```
gtfDict = {"human": "/path/to/human.gtf",
           "mouse": "/path/to/mouse.gtf"}

rule count_reads:
    input:
        ibam = "sorted_reads/{specie}/{spc}_sorted.bam",
        gtf = lambda wildcards: gtfDict[wildcards.specie]
    output:
        bam = "counted_reads/{specie}/{spc}_countBAM.bam",
        htout = "counted_reads/{specie}/{spc}_htseq_count.out"
    log:
        "logs/count_reads/{specie}/{spc}.log"
    shell:
        "htseq-count -o {output.bam} -p bam {input.ibam} {input.gtf} > {output.htout} 2> {log}"
```

Comment: `lambda` is one way to do it. More generally, you need a function of wildcards as input. `lambda` is a special syntax in Python to define a function on-the-fly. It could be more readable to define a function upstream in your code, using the `def` keyword, and name the function (`def set_gtf_input(wildcards): ...`). And then, in your `input` section: `gtf = set_gtf_input`.